# Solr facet results differ on each query

Tags: caching, solr, lucene, facet, faceted-search

I'm running Solr 4.1 and have many facet counts defined. I noticed that when I send the same query to Solr multiple times, the result facet counts differ each time. For some reason, my filterCache is causing the first query result's facet counts to be different than all subsequent queries. When I remove my filterCache from the config, I do not see this issue at all.

Why does filterCache cause this inconsistency? Here's all the caching I have in my configs:

```
     <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="32"/>

    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="1024"
                     initialSize="1024"
                     autowarmCount="512"/>

    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="1024"
                   initialSize="1024"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>

    <queryResultWindowSize>10</queryResultWindowSize>


   <queryResultMaxDocsCached>100</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
```